# Forward consent to Facebook Audience Network SDK (GDPR)

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I've added Consent SDK from Google, and I've written code to pass consent from EU users to Admob SDK by doing something like below:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("npa", "1");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, bundle).build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Now, I've searched a lot in Facebook documentation, and the Google Consent SDK page [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent) carries me [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook#eu_consent_and_gdpr), and after going on that, I'm carried to useless page which only tells me about GDPR, i.e. https://www.facebook.com/business/gdpr.

Basically, what I'm trying to say is I've searched a lot, and I couldn't find anything related to passing user consent to Facebook SDK.

Does anyone know how to pass consent to FAN SDK while requesting Ads on Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Facebook handles this in another way.

In order to show relevant ads, the user must have used the Facebook app. If no advertisement is shown, it is because the user has not logged in to the app in the last 30 days.

The user has to have consented to targeted ads from within the Facebook apps.

If those conditions are not met, the ad is not shown

> The person using your app or site has turned off targeted advertising in his or her device settings.

You can read more about this in [this link](https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/1673395492911956/)

**Update September 23, 2020**

Here I leave more information about how Facebook processes the data

Facebook Privacy Links:

- [Data Policy](https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/)
- [Cookies & Other Storage Technologies](https://www.facebook.com/policies/cookies/)
- [Privacy Basics](https://www.facebook.com/about/basics/)